# Human Tracking based on Affinity Measures

Tags: computer-vision, tracking

I am currently trying to track persons in a CCTV footage. Basically currently I used HOG + SVM + scanning window to generate bounding boxes at each frame to identify heads (of each person). The heads where chosen as the full body is mostly covered by other humans because of the angle of the CCTV. This is acceptable as currently I am not looking at efficiency.

However, my next stage is to associate these bounding boxes together so as to put a person's bounding boxes at separate frames in one single track.

I am currently using colour and LBP histograms as affinity measures and also overlapping. I.e. if it overlaps it must be that of the same person. And if the histogram distances (based on histogram intersection) is low it also must be the same person.

Questions:
1). First and foremost I would like to know if someone out there know how occlusion can be handled in this way. I.e. if a person is seen last in 2nd frame and then in 5th frame. Do you know a strong affinity measure which can help me identify that it is of the same person? Keep in mind that sometimes the persons can change their head orientation.

2). Maybe any ideas about more affinity measures?

Your help is very much appreciated.
P.S. : In case of the need for further clarifications, tell me, I can explain better.

Answer (score 0):

Re #1: I recommend looking at particle filters and the condensation algorithm.

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_filter
http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condensation_algorithm